# LaTeXTidy in Emacs

Tags: formatting, emacs

I often use [Eric Tsu's LaTeXTidy script](http://bfc.sfsu.edu/cgi-bin/hsu.pl?LaTeX_Tidy) to neaten LaTeX files in TextMate, which includes it in the LaTeX bundle. I press a key-binding and LaTeXTidy formats the file. One can do this multiple times while editing a document and not leave TextMate.

I have looked, but have not found how to use this script in Emacs, although it seems like it would not be difficult to implement for a more experienced Emacs user: running a Perl script on an open LaTeX file by pressing a key-binding. Being new to Emacs, it might be more difficult than I think.

How would I run this script on an open LaTeX file in Emacs?

Comment: "This is released as Niceware, which is like the Perl Artistic License, except you have to be nice to me when you criticize the code." I like this guy.

Comment: I would look into using eshell to do some buffer-text redirection.

Comment: Thank you, Sean. This is my first time seeing the terms "eshell" and "buffer-text redirection," but if I am to become an Emacs user, I probably should start learning! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

The following code, when you modify `path-to-latex-tidy.pl` to the correct location, will pass the contents of the current buffer to that program, and then replace the buffer contents with the result. I don't have latex-tidy on hand to test it with, so check it with something disposable before you do something sensitive with this. You *should* be able to back out of any changes via undo, but that sometimes is an issue when making extensive changes to a large buffer.

```el
(defun latex-tidy ()
  "Replace the contents of the current buffer with the output of
latex-tidy"
  (interactive)
  (shell-command-on-region
   (point-min)
   (point-max)
   (format "cat %s > path-to-latex-tidy.pl" (buffer-file-name))
   nil t))
```

You can bind that to a key in the usual ways, such as:

```
(global-set-key [f9] #'latex-tidy)
```

Note, however, that you may be better off taking full advantage of the facilities AucTex provides for formatting your text as you write it. Using latex-tidy may lead to situations where AucTex and latex-tidy continually reverse each other's decisions, which could cause problems.

Comment: @SeanAllred the sharp quote #' is not necessary here, a regular quote ' is fine, and is the normal syntax used in the Emacs manual

Comment: Maybe it's not strictly necessary but it's useful: http://endlessparentheses.com/get-in-the-habit-of-using-sharp-quote.html

Comment: @Tyler Always be as explicit as possible without being wordy :) and I wouldn't hold the emacs manual in such high regard with respect to style ;)

Comment: @Tyler My apologies for taking so long to reply. I copied your code into my init.el, changed the path, and restarted emacs. When I press f9, the buffer goes blank, but C-x u works. In any case, it's not important to me now, since I took your other advice and am using the formatting options in AucTeX. Thank you!